# QListView Maintain Selection and Check All Selected

Tags: python, pyside

I'm trying to find a way in which I can do the following:

- When a user clicks an item in the list, if there is a selection made, it maintains the selected items and changes all their checkboxes to match the checkbox of the clicked item
- Maintain selection of items when clicking checkboxes. Currently the QListView clears the row selection when clicking a checkbox of an item within the selected rows. however when a user clicks a checkbox outside the selected rows, it properly retains the selection. The selection should only be lost if a user clicks on the row, not the checkbox.

Could anyone help me out in overriding what happens when a checkbox is clicked to achieve my goals?

[image]

```
import os, sys
from Qt import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class CheckableDictionaryListView(QtWidgets.QListView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(CheckableDictionaryListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300,300)
        self.filters = {}

        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())
        self.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ActionsContextMenu)

        # Begin
        self.setItems(['item 00','item 01','item 02','item 03','item 05','item 06','item 07','item 08','item 09','item 10'])


    # Methods
    def setItems(self, lst):
        model = self.model().sourceModel()
        model.clear()
        for x in lst:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setData(x, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            model.appendRow(item)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = CheckableDictionaryListView()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    main()
```

Comment: From what I understand in case 1 you mean that the multiselection is with just the click and you do not need the help of a key, in addition to the previously selected items must have the same checkbox status of the item pressed. What happens if you press an item already selected? Should only that item be deselected? Should the checkbox status be changed to match this item?

Comment: You still have to use Ctrl+Click to multi select items. However when a user clicks the checkbox it should toggle the selected items to match the checkstate of the clicked index's checkbox.

Comment: When a Selected item's checkbox is clicked, it should change the state of all the other selected items to match the checkstate of the clicked item.

Comment: My question goes in the sense that if an item currently has the selection and is clicked, common sense tells me that it should be deselected, if so, should the checkboxes of the other items that are selected be changed?

Comment: When you say 'item currently has selection is clicked' do you mean the checkbox is clicked, or the item's display text is clicked?

Comment: If the item's display text is clicked, it should be deselected. But if the checkbox is clicked, it should remain selected and all other items currently selected should update their checkboxes to match the one clicked.

Comment: Here is a video demonstrating how many applications Checkboxes work, and im trying to recreate this in pyside. https://vimeo.com/331124857/c509c7b47b

Comment: @eyllanesc The biggest thing I'm after is being able to toggle the checkstate for the selected items. If a user has 5 items selected and clicks the checkbox within the selected items, i want the remaining items to change to match the new checkstate.  As far as selection goes, that's far less important to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection` as selectionMode in addition to overwriting the editorEvent method to prevent the view from handling the click event when it is pressed in the checkbox:

```py
import os, sys
from Qt import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class StyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        last_state = index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        val = super(StyledItemDelegate, self).editorEvent(
            event, model, option, index
        )
        if last_state != index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole):
            return True
        return val


class CheckableDictionaryListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableDictionaryListView, self).__init__(parent)
        delegate = StyledItemDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred
        )
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))
        self.setModel(self.proxyModel)

        # after set model
        self.model().dataChanged.connect(self.onDataChanged)
        self.setItems(
            [
                "item 00",
                "item 01",
                "item 02",
                "item 03",
                "item 05",
                "item 06",
                "item 07",
                "item 08",
                "item 09",
                "item 10",
            ]
        )

    def setItems(self, lst):
        model = self.model().sourceModel()
        model.clear()
        for x in lst:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setData(x, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            model.appendRow(item)

    @QtCore.Slot("QModelIndex", "QModelIndex", int)
    def onDataChanged(self, tl, br, roles):
        if QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole in roles:
            if tl == br and tl in self.selectedIndexes():
                state = tl.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
                self.model().blockSignals(True)
                for ix in self.selectedIndexes():
                    self.model().setData(ix, state, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
                self.model().blockSignals(False)


def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    ex = CheckableDictionaryListView()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: This partially does what i want the Extended selection mode however more closely reacts the way I would want the selection mode to work. The only problem is that it doesn't maintain selected when an item's data is changed. Multiselect mode is not a common or user friendly mode. Can't say i know of any application that works like that, so i would avoid using it.

Comment: @JokerMartini mmm, I do not understand you, do you want to keep the selection even when the user is editing a text?

Comment: In short I want to use the extended selection mode. not the MultiSelection mode. I do not like that selection mode, it's not a common mode people are familiar with.

Comment: @JokerMartini Well, trying to implement the same functionality with ExtendedSelection could be complicated, not because of the difficulty but because of the time that would have to be spent to pay for the logic of QListView, and since I did not see a logic in your last comment more than a personal taste, I ended my help in this answer. bye :-)